# XML- Denormalizing repeating siblings

Tags: xml, xslt

We send out target files to vendors and they can contain 0-30 optional fields.  Our XSD works to transfer to normalized DB but it isn't so good for a low tech print vendor.  So I wanted to use an XSLT to create a denormalized view of the data that even a basic user could decode with Excel.  The trick is not every record has the same or same number optional fields and I don't know how to align this to work.

```
<target>
        <transactionNumber>536880912</transactionNumber>
       <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>PROMO_CODE</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>ABC127</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>cell</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>2</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
  </target>
  <target>
        <transactionNumber>536880924</transactionNumber>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>PROMO_CODE</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>ABC131</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
  </target>
<target>
        <transactionNumber>536880213</transactionNumber>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
        <optionalField>
            <optionalFieldLabel>cell</optionalFieldLabel>
            <optionalFieldDescription>1</optionalFieldDescription>
        </optionalField>
  </target>
```

I'm new here so no images :(

I'm trying for something like this:

536880912___PROMO_CODE___ABC127___Version___CON___cell___2

536880924___PROMO_CODE___ABC131___Version___CON

536880213_____________________________Version___CON___cell___1

Or an HTML table where my optionalfieldlabel is the header of each column.

**I just came to the realization how to simplify my problem.**
Basically I just need strip out the optionfield and optionalfieldlabel tags and replace them with the with a new tag using the optionalfieldlabel value.  So it transforms to look like this:

```
<target>
        <transactionNumber>536880912</transactionNumber>
       <PROMO_CODE>
            <optionalFieldDescription>ABC127</optionalFieldDescription>
        </PROMO_CODE>
        <Version>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </Version>
        <cell>
            <optionalFieldDescription>2</optionalFieldDescription>
        </cell>
  </target>
  <target>
        <transactionNumber>536880924</transactionNumber>
        <PROMO_CODE>
            <optionalFieldDescription>ABC131</optionalFieldDescription>
        </PROMO_CODE>
        <Version>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </Version>
  </target>
<target>
        <transactionNumber>536880912</transactionNumber>
        <Version>
            <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
        </Version>
        <cell>
            <optionalFieldDescription>1</optionalFieldDescription>
        </cell>
  </target>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried so far - Your question is missing your XSLT. Also, I don't quite get all the underscores in your desired output - Why not a simple csv?

Comment: The underscores were to align my example output, form didn't align using tabs ignore them.

Comment: No XSLT since nothing I did was even close to working.  A csv would be great actually, but the key there would be inserting extra commas for records without the same optional fields.  Thanks.

Comment: Re your updated question: are you sure? I believe that should be quite easy to do (unlike your previous request), but why should it make a difference? -- Note also that both your input and output are missing a root element.

Comment: Yes I am sure.  I agree this much simpler, but it is what our printer really want...a simple .csv like file.  They aren't loading this to a database, they just want to do a glorified mail merge.  Half of them are just stripping the tag off using a .csv file converter.  I left the root element off for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I just need strip out the optionfield and
>   optionalfieldlabel tags and replace them with the with a new tag using
>   the optionalfieldlabel value.

This is rather trivial to do, using the *identity transform* template to copy everything as is, except the `optionalField` element that is handled by a dedicated template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="optionalField">
    <xsl:element name="{optionalFieldLabel}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="optionalFieldDescription"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to a **corrected** input of:

```
<root>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880912</transactionNumber>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>PROMO_CODE</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>ABC127</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>cell</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>2</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
   </target>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880924</transactionNumber>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>PROMO_CODE</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>ABC131</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
   </target>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880213</transactionNumber>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>Version</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
      <optionalField>
         <optionalFieldLabel>cell</optionalFieldLabel>
         <optionalFieldDescription>1</optionalFieldDescription>
      </optionalField>
   </target>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880912</transactionNumber>
      <PROMO_CODE>
         <optionalFieldDescription>ABC127</optionalFieldDescription>
      </PROMO_CODE>
      <Version>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </Version>
      <cell>
         <optionalFieldDescription>2</optionalFieldDescription>
      </cell>
   </target>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880924</transactionNumber>
      <PROMO_CODE>
         <optionalFieldDescription>ABC131</optionalFieldDescription>
      </PROMO_CODE>
      <Version>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </Version>
   </target>
   <target>
      <transactionNumber>536880213</transactionNumber>
      <Version>
         <optionalFieldDescription>CON</optionalFieldDescription>
      </Version>
      <cell>
         <optionalFieldDescription>1</optionalFieldDescription>
      </cell>
   </target>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed it was trivial...I just wish it were trivial for me :)  I'm more of a business analyst now, I used to hack 20 years ago so I'm trying to get back into it some. Some of these easier things aren't worth the time of putting into our corporate development queue, they would never be considered high enough priority to get done but they make a huge impact on the support side.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the stylesheet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/target"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="target">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="transactionNumber"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='PROMO_CODE']"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='PROMO_CODE']/following-sibling::optionalFieldDescription"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='Version']"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='Version']/following-sibling::optionalFieldDescription"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='cell']"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="optionalField/optionalFieldLabel[.='cell']/following-sibling::optionalFieldDescription"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I guess this will be a starting point for you to go further. You have to know exactly the complete 30 fields and where to place them.

Comment: There's the rub.  The field labels will vary by file, every job is different.  Sorry I wasn't clear about that before.  I don't know if there is some type of array function where you could read the whole file and store every unique one before you process the file.